# What is a word for someone who turns to religion for hope?

Tags: single-word-requests

By this, I mean someone who is not extremely religious, but, in a time of crisis, will turn to religion for hope. An example would be a mother who prays if her daughter is kidnapped, but does not pray on a daily basis. Is there a word for this?

Comment: God's fair weather friend?

Comment: @CandiedOrange I would say that is the closest one there is.Good answer.

Comment: Perhaps a "casual supplicant" ? (*a ​supplicant ​asks a ​god -or someone who is in a ​position of ​power- for something in a ​humble way*)

Comment: You talk as if everyone's daughter gets kidnapped once in a while! If you are only going to pray when that happens, it certainly will not be very often for the average person.

Comment: Maybe a little unorthodox but a saying I know is "No one's an atheist in a foxhole." You could maybe call someone an atheist in a foxhole, but I'm not sure the reference would be widely understood or parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"God's fair weather friend" is an expression, not a single word but a search with this text will turn up lots of articles on exactly this subject.

Note: this is a better answer for the body of your question then for it's title.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Should it not be *God's bad weather friend*?

Comment: @WS2 It does rather invert the metaphor but do a search for both and tell me which you find to be the more popular.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not 100% as you describe it. But, [Repentance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repentance) seems close enough.

> Repentance is the activity of reviewing one's actions and feeling contrition or regret for past wrongs. It generally involves a commitment to personal change and the resolve to live a more responsible and humane life.

One could also attempt to use words like: *salvation*, *deliverance* and *redemption* or a combination of thereof, to deliver a similar message.

Answer (score 0):

**Petty fidian** goes a long way back. [Oxford(ish)](http://findwords.info/term/petty%20fidian):

> petty fidian petty ˈfidianObs.nonce-wd.
>   [f. petty a. + L. fid-ēs faith + -ian.]
>   One ‘of little faith’.
>   1647 Trapp Comm. Matt. viii. 26 O ye of little faith. Ye petty fidians; He calleth them not nullifidians. Ibid. xiv. 31 Thou petty-fidian, small-faith: Christ chides Peter, and yet helps him.

**Nullifidians** being atheists, and **[solifidians](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solifidian)** go so far the other way as to believe that salvation comes through faith, not works.

-- That was an **Odd** little search!